# Python savgol_filter returns nan

Tags: python, filter, scipy, nan

I'm using the savgol_filter to smooth some data, but sometimes I get just 'nan' as output.
Not sure, what the issue is... it mostly occurs with longer data arrays (over 1000 entries).

Here's the code:

```
SmoothMeasurement = savgol_filter(Measurement, 81, 3, delta=0.5)
```

To be honest, I'm not sure what the arguments are for. I just know that the difference between the two numbers determines the 'smoothness'. I checked the 'Measurement' array so that's not the problem.

Comment: It will be much easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is the shape of `Measurement`? Also, you are specifying `delta`, but it is only used if a non-default `deriv` is given.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) is pretty clear. The second argument is the window length over which the interpolation is done, third argument is the order of polynomial to use.